ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression on Order
When I put order by, I get an error that ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression, and I've no idea what happen, could you please tell me what should I do?
Select distinct
FL.MEANING||' : '||FL.Tag||' : '||FL.DESCRIPTION  as BU_NAME
from
FND_LOOKUPS FL
INNER JOIN FUN_ALL_BUSINESS_UNITS_V fabuv on FL.DESCRIPTION = fabuv.BU_NAME 
where
FL.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'MINOR BU' 
ORDER BY FL.MEANING 

